# app.config not refreshing or being created from project modifications in VS17

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, console-application, visual-studio-2017, app-config

Never had this happen before but my app.config is not being updated or created from the VS project, inside my bin/debug folder.  It keeps retrieving some other values, and I am not sure where from.

If I do a clean on the project the bin/debug is cleared, then a rebuild creates all the files again, but the app.config is not the same one in my project.  Where can I look to see where it is creating this file from?

This is a console application in .NET 4.7 in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Just guessing here but could you have more than one project in the solution and the app.config from another project (maybe a class library) get copied in the bin folder for the console app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I deleted the `obj/debug` folder and it cleared up the problem.  Something must have been cached or stuck.

Comment: Since this issue has been resolved, you could mark it as the answer, thanks for your sharing. Have a nice day.